# JavaScript Area Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was doing a simple JS DOM practice exercise. It is supposed to multiply the area of the two variables the user enters into the input boxes. But right when I thought I finished it, my code didn't work.

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one").value;
var two = document.getElementById("two").value;
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function calculate() {
  output.innerHTML = one * two;
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = calculate();
```

```html
<h1>Area Calculator for Rectangles</h1>
<form>
  Side Length One<br>
  <input type="text" id="one"><br> Side Length Two<br>
  <input type="text" id="two">

</form>
<button id="button">SUBMIT</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: `But right when I thought I finished it, my code didn't work.` what does it mean? your code didn't work? Can you edit your code to a snippet using `<>` in the toolbar?

Comment: I created a snippet for you. You also need to make the button `type="button"` - I would put the vars inside the function to be sure they are new and available when you run it and remove the `()` from `button.onclick = calculate();` and lastly assign the onclick in a page onload

Comment: because you need to get new values on each calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, There are so many misunderstandings going on in some of the answers so I'll post my version and convert my comments to this answer.

- the button needs to be `type="button"` OR make it submit and use the submit handler of the form - see example 2
- put the vars inside the function to be sure they are new and available when you run it
- remove the () from `button.onclick = calculate();` since you now assign the result of calculate to the onclick instead of the handler. In my example I use an anonymous function instead.
- assign the onclick in a page onload to be sure the button had rendered when you assign the handler

```js
window.onload=function() { // the page has loaded - anonymous function
  document.getElementById("button").onclick=function() { // anonymous function
    var one = document.getElementById("one").value, // using commas to separate vars
        two = document.getElementById("two").value,  
     output = document.getElementById("output");

    output.innerHTML = one * two;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Area Calculator for Rectangles</h1>
<form>
  Side Length One<br>
  <input type="text" id="one"><br> Side Length Two<br>
  <input type="text" id="two">

</form>
<button type="button" id="button">SUBMIT</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Since you have a form, you can use submit event - note the event is cancelled using preventDefault. Useful if you need to send a result to the server later using Ajax for example:

```js
window.onload=function() { // the page has loaded - anonymous function
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function(e) { // anonymous function
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submission - note the event passed as "e"
    var one = document.getElementById("one").value, // using commas to separate vars
        two = document.getElementById("two").value,  
     output = document.getElementById("output");

    output.innerHTML = one * two;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Area Calculator for Rectangles</h1>
<form id="form1">
  Side Length One<br>
  <input type="text" id="one"><br/> Side Length Two<br>
  <input type="text" id="two"><br/>
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Submitting a form is an unwanted thing

Comment: @Nitheesh - as you can see, I am not submitting, just using the submit event of the already existing form.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to get values at the time of button click. So, move it inside `calculate()` function. Second, to `onClick` property you have to assign a function. So, don't execute it, just assign the function like `prop=funName`.

```js
var one, two; 
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function calculate() {
  one = document.getElementById("one").value;    //Change1
  two = document.getElementById("two").value;    //Change1
  output.innerHTML = one * two;
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = calculate;                      //Change2
```

```html
<h1>Area Calculator for Rectangles</h1>
<form>
  Side Length One<br>
  <input type="text" id="one"><br> Side Length Two<br>
  <input type="text" id="two">

</form>
<button id="button">SUBMIT</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

As `@mplungjan` mentioned in the comments, it is better to use `window.onload` listener to make sure all dom elements are completed loading(before trying to access them).

Answer (score 0):

Set the onclick event on the dom element or define an eventListener for it. Also fetch the values of inputs inside the `calculate` function otherwise it will only be fetched once.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var one = document.getElementById("one").value;
    var two = document.getElementById("two").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML = one * two;
});
```

```html
<h1>Area Calculator for Rectangles</h1>
    <form>
      Side Length One<br>
      <input type="text" id="one"><br>

      Side Length Two<br>
      <input type="text" id="two">

    </form>
    <button id="button" >SUMBIT</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
```

However in your case you only need to call the onclick function like `button.onclick = calculate;` instead of `button.onclick = calculate();` and get the values inside the calculate function

```js
function calculate() {
var one = document.getElementById("one").value;
var two = document.getElementById("two").value;
var output = document.getElementById("output");

  output.innerHTML = one * two;
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = calculate;
```

```html
<h1>Area Calculator for Rectangles</h1>
    <form>
      Side Length One<br>
      <input type="text" id="one"><br>

      Side Length Two<br>
      <input type="text" id="two">

    </form>
    <button id="button" >SUMBIT</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: element.onclick is actually more compatible - also note that your script must run after dom is ready

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things you were doing incorrectly that causes some errors:

1. You invoked the `calculate` function when assigning it to the button's `onclick` handler. In javascript, functions are first class citizens and there is a big difference in the code `calculate` and `calculate()`. When assigning a value to an onclick handler, don't invoke the function.
2. You weren't getting the `value`s of the the elements `one` and `two` inside the `calculate` function. When they were invoked, they didn't grab the current value. Place the `.value` property access inside your calculate function and it should work as expected!

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function calculate() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one").value;
  var two = document.getElementById("two").value;
  output.innerHTML = one * two;
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = calculate;
```

```html
<h1>Area Calculator for Rectangles</h1>
<form>
  Side Length One<br>
  <input type="text" id="one"><br> Side Length Two<br>
  <input type="text" id="two">

</form>
<button id="button">SUMBIT</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain why your code doesn't work. When your JS is executed by the browser, it brings in the value of `one` and `two`. Now your `calculate` method references the value that was saved earlier. So it is not referencing the value at the time of the button being clicked.

Bring in the calls to get the value for `one` and `two` inside the calculate method and you should be good to go

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function calculate() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one").value;
  var two = document.getElementById("two").value;
  output.innerHTML = one * two;
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = calculate;
```

```html
<h1>Area Calculator for Rectangles</h1>
    <form>
      Side Length One<br>
      <input type="text" id="one"><br>

      Side Length Two<br>
      <input type="text" id="two">

    </form>
    <button id="button" >SUMBIT</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: @mplungjan, I've added the snipped